# how to use loop to get expenses from 01-09-2015 to 31-09-2015 in my expenses table

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table having two columns date and expenses. I want to retrieve daily expenses in a month using loop concept in plsql. Can anyone say how this is possible?

Comment: there is no 31 september :). 30 days hath september, april, june and november, all the rest have 31 except february alone which has 28 days clear, 29 each leap year -lol

Comment: Post the sample data of the table and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your table structure etc. I've had a guess.
Also, this is a very basic way of doing it in a PL/SQL loop, you haven't said if you want it in a procedure or what you want t do with the data once you have retrieved it so I have simply output it via DBMS_OUTPUT.

Also, I have used hard coded dates as your info about what dates to use is patchy too.

If you want a more tailored response, you should ask a more specific question, I hope this goes some way to helping you solve your issue.

```
BEGIN
   FOR c_rec IN (SELECT expenses_date,  -- Put actual column name in here
                        expenses_amount -- Put actual column name in here
                   FROM expenses        -- Put actual table name in here
                  WHERE expenses_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-09-2015', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
                                          AND TO_DATE('30-09-2015', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
   LOOP
      -- Do what you want here with the data you have retrieved in the loop
      dbms_output.put_line('Date: '||c_rec.expenses_date||', Expenses: '||c_rec.expenses_amount);
   END LOOP;
END;
```